# Encoding in Python / RML with Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, reportlab, utf8-decode

I use ReportLab and RML to create invoices.
On my test system there is no problem with german umlaute like ß in Straße

but on the Production System it gives me:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /abrechnung/abrechnung/angebot/2/print/

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 513: ordinal not in range(128)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://eu-con-app.de/webapps/gerloff/abrechnung/abrechnung/angebot/2/print/
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 513: ordinal not in range(128)

Exception Location:     /webapps/gerloff/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py in decode, line 26
Python Executable:  /webapps/gerloff/bin/python3.4
Python Version:     3.4.3
Python Path:    

['/webapps/gerloff/gerloff_ltw',
 '/webapps/gerloff/bin',
 '/webapps/gerloff/gerloff_ltw',
 '/webapps/gerloff/lib/python3.4',
 '/webapps/gerloff/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/webapps/gerloff/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/webapps/gerloff/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

while the test machine produces no error.

I tested both with similar settings - main diffrent is, that the production code is run by gunicorn and the test code is delivered by djangos testserver.

Comment: Two different versions of python: one 2.x, the other 3.x.

Comment: Was also my first idea, but both run via virtualenv - and the debug page states it is python 3.4.3. My test system has python 3 as default but the productiv server uses 2.7.3 as main. Then again I use virtualenvs for the projects

Comment: Well, in your test system virutalenv, do `$ python --version`.  And in your production virtualenv do `$ python --version`.

Comment: *but the productiv server uses 2.7.3*,--And that makes sense.

Comment: Inside the virtual env: 3.4.3 (both) outside 2.7.3(prod); 3.5.1(test)

Comment: So what I do not understand is, why doesn't the virtual env prevent this?

Comment: Shebang line? ...........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98468/discussion-between-maximilian-kindshofer-and-7stud).

Comment: There can be environmental differences that also affect how strings are automatically decoded, eg when opening a file with specifying an `encoding` argument. You need to look at (/post code for) the parts of the code that are fetching the address string in question and ensure that they specify an explicit encoding, whichever one is correct for the byte content in question.

Comment: what is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` in both cases?

Comment: This seems to get to the root of the problem -> Testserver = UTF-8 and Productiv = 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I changed the environment so that it is UTF-8 on both machines and it works - so if you like to write an answer to the question I could accept it.